# Barcode Scanner Issue in Cordova 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, cordova, ios7, barcode-scanner

I'm using the Barcode Scanner plugin with Cordova, and the camera keep freezing when I navigate through my app.

It throws the following warning in XCode :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <CDVbcsViewController> on <MainViewController> while a presentation is in progress!
```

Do you have any ideas how I could solve this issue ?

edit:

Maybe it has something to do with Backbone as I'm browsing the app. The Barcode scan goes well when i'm on the homepage, but as soon as I change the page, it's freezing and I got the warning.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
        <title>Project</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

plugin_cordova.js

```
cordova.define('cordova/plugin_list', function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = [
    {
        "file": "plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/www/barcodescanner.js",
        "id": "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner",
        "clobbers": [
            "cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner"
        ]
    }
]
});
```

my backbone view

```
define(['jquery','underscore','backbone'], function($, _, Backbone){
  var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
      /* ... */
    },
    render: function(ev){
      /* ... */
    }
    startScan: function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      cordova.plugins.barcodeScanner.scan(this.scanSuccess,this.scanError);
    },
    scanSuccess: function(response){
      alert("We got a barcode\n" +
            "Result: " + response.text + "\n" +
            "Format: " + response.format + "\n" +
            "Cancelled: " + response.cancelled);
    },
    scanError: function(error){
      alert('Error: '+error);
    },
  });
  return myView;
});
```

Thanks!

Comment: using barcodeScanner.js?

Comment: I'm using barcodescanner.js indeed. I'm also using require.js and backbone to build my app. As a matter of fact, the barcode scan works well right after the app has launched ( i get the success / error callback and everything ). But as soon as I navigate through some pages, when I try to launch the scan I got this error. I'll update my post with some code.

Comment: @hussainShabbir i put up some code. i'm starting to think it may be linked with backbone...

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the similar warning recently. After some investigation, triggering the barcode scanner more than once at the same time will have this problem. This could be due to multiple times binding of the button that trigger scanner.